# How to create an object with a combination of methods?

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a versatile custom object `converter` which should be able to,

- read from XML and write to XML
- read from XML and write to CSV
- read from CSV and write to XML
- read from CSV and write to CSV

So, I thought I could do smth like :

```
Converter
{
   IReader reader;
   IWriter writer;
}

IReader
{
 read();
}
```

..(same for writer)
then instantiate a Converter from one of each, implementing interface:

```
new Converter(XMLReader, CSVWriter);
```

(where `XMLReader implements IReader` & `CSVWriter implements IWriter`)

But then again, it would be cooler to be able to keep the XML related classes together too.

Can be a simple question with a simple answer, but I was wondering if we could come up with a more elegant solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have defined classes for XML sources and CSV sources, why not a `Converter<IN, OUT>` interface which you'd implement for all cases?

Comment: that d make 4 classes tho, no? could you explain maybe a bit more?

Comment: Well, three actually since you can implement an `IdentityConverter<T>` as a `Converter<T, T>` ;) You do not really tell much about your reader/writer interfaces though, so it is difficult to come with a "perfect" solution

Answer (score 2):

Your design is fine. If you want to group your classes together use packages. For example create packages: `com.mycompany.xml` and `com.mycompany.csv`. Then put `CsvReader` and `CsvWriter` to `com.mycompany.csv` and `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` to `com.mycompany.xml`.